How to add 2 rigify-charcters in 1 scene
I have 2 characters, in 2 different scenes, equipped with rigify. How do I put them in the same scene? I use Blender 3.6.9.

There are three ways in general:

You can rig the characters in the same scene from the start

You can Append them from separate files (File > Append).

You can Link them from separate files (File > Link)


For linking or appending, it's best to place the entire character (rig and mesh) in a Collection and Link/Append the collection rather than the individual parts.
If you go for Linking: right-click on the imported collection in the Outliner > Library Override > Make > Content to make your character usable in the scene.
Difference between Link/Append: Append creates a full copy of the character in the new scene. Link creates a reference to the data from the other fine. Link uses less space and if you make any changes to the original file, they will show up in the linked character as soon as you reload the file.
These are the basics.

Ok, thanks. I'l try.
